# Optimization Question - Distance to the Origin

Tags: calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I came across a question that asked what the furthest point from the origin subject to a constraint ie. $x^4+y^4+3xy=2$. It was an optimization question and we were told to use Lagrangian Multiplier. In the answer, they made the objective function $x^{2}+y^{2}$ but shouldn't it be $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$? If not, why?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Technically you're correct that the distance function is $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.  However, it's easier to work with $x^2+y^2$ and that obviously has the same extrema.

Comment: @RobertShore Thanks for answering! I realize that it's easier to use, my question is how does that work? Obviously, x^2+y^2 =! sqrt(x^2+y^2), and their derivatives are different as well... So why would their extrema be the same?

Comment: Because $\frac {d}{dx}\sqrt{f(x)}=\frac{f'(x)}{2\sqrt{f(x)}}$ so their derivatives have the same zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

Because $\sqrt{z}$ is an increasing function of $z$, optimizing $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ is equivalent to optimizing $x^2+y^2$.  The same approach is often used with $\log(z)$ as the increasing function instead of $\sqrt{z}$, especially for maximizing likelihood, which is usually expressed as a product.  In that case, the motivation is that $\log$ transforms products to sums, and it is generally easier to differentiate sums.